# Python function: How to calculate x in a cubic equation using python

Tags: python, function, optimization, cubic

How to find the value of x from the equation `calculate_density(x)`?

I have the following Python function:

```py
a = 5108.30
b = 3967550
c = -281375000
pressure = 100
def calculate_density(x):
    density = (a * x + b * x**2 + c * x**3) * pressure
    return density
```

The function takes in a value for x and returns the density value. I want to find the value of x from the equation when the density is given.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

```
x_solution = fsolve(equation, x_initial_guess, args=(a, b, c, density, pressure))
```

but the results are not giving me optimal solution

Comment: Is there an optimal solution to your density function? Also, `args` doesn't do what you think it does, I think, since `calculate_density` isn't a function of the args you passed.

Comment: Have you tried using `sympy.solve()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your equation is a cubic polynomial, you could have 3 values for `x`. To find the roots, you can use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def fsolve(a, b, c, density, pressure):
    return np.roots([c,b,a,-density/pressure])
```